# Add a new group for an existing user failed: permission denied

Tags: linux

I my server Linux debian 7 I used to add users for an existing group as following:

```
useradd -G {group-name} username
```

But Is there any way to do the opposite: add a new group for an existing user name?
I tried this but it fails: `groupadd -u username groupname`
I am trying to add a new group for an existing user just to test why this command fails: because via plesk some procedures cannot be done indicating that:`filemng: Unable to init new groups for user X  Operation not permitted` despite my directory `/etc/group` has the right permissions:755
Any idea how to run this command via Terminal ssh client(add a group to an existing user) just to debug the permissions issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
usermod -G groupname username
```

[`man usermod`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/usermod)

Of course, the group has to be added with `groupadd groupname` first.

Comment: I choosed an arbitrary username but this command failed indicating that no such an existing group `usermod: group 'groupname' does not exist` ..

Comment: This is no helping to add a NEW group